# Touchmove event stops triggering after any element is removed from dom

Tags: javascript, html, touch, mobile-safari

On touch devices such as iPad (or **mobile emulaton mode** in chrome). When tracking `touchmove` event on body and removing an element (on which touchstart started) from dom `touchmove` events from body stops triggering.

I made an **example**: http://jsbin.com/yinodosuxo/1/edit?js,console,output

Is there any way for the `touchmove` continue working even after the child element is removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by caching the element until `touchend` event is emitted.
The pseudo code for the view that triggered the `touchstart` event would look something like this:

```
view.remove = function () {
  if (didViewStartTouchEvents) {
    var _this = this;
    this.hideElement(); // display: none, opacity: 0, etc
    elementCache.appendChild(this); //append this element to some other place like body. Not needed but might be handy depending on situation
    document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
      _this.didViewStartTouchEvents = false;
      _this.remove();
    });
  } else {
    // regular remove & cleanup
  }
}
```